# One Time Password for Frontend user login

Tags: login, secure

Can I configure the Magento frontend user login to incorporate a One Time password via a text message on the registered phone number? If yes what are the areas i need to factor in?

Comment: Can you give more details? Describe "on time password". What should happen on the second login attempt?

Comment: I want to provide an automatic one time password by text message each time a user wants to logs in. So in effect there is 2 level protection. Maybe somewhat like this - "http://www.xtento.com/magento-extensions/two-factor-authentication-enhanced-admin-security.html" but i dont want to use Google Authenticator

Comment: Haven't tried anything yet, looking for solutions.

Comment: I have a solution i.e. the developer API provided by bulksms.com

Comment: @anna and others, i was looking for a solution for a requirement which came my way, and got the same, which I have posted here in the comments, i.e. the API provided by bulksms.com